# Default WPF HitTest behaviour with Hidden/Collapsed elements

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hittest

in WPF when using `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` even hidden Elements are found. To skip this elements and only return a result for visible ones, i created a `HitTestFilter` like the following :

```cs
///This Filter should cut all invisible or not HitTest Enabled Elements
private static HitTestFilterBehavior MyHitTestFilter(DependencyObject target)
{
    var uiElement = target as UIElement;
    if (uiElement != null){
        if(!uiElement.IsHitTestVisible || !uiElement.IsVisible))
            return HitTestFilterBehavior.ContinueSkipSelfAndChildren;
    }
    return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
}
```

This Filter does his job, but i like to know what the default WPF HitTesting does in this case? Does it use a similar filter? Are there any other, maybe better options for doing this?

**To clarify a short description :**

[image: Layout example]

In the image there is

1. A Layout Container as the root element
2. Button1 which is visible
3. Above Button1 is Button2 which is invisible

If i got such a layout and do a mouseclick in the green area of Button2, WPF skips Button2 and the click event appears on Button1.

If i do manual HitTesting without the filter described earlier, i will get Button2 as the result.

So the question is, what is the default behaviour/filter WPF is using?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Can't reproduce this for Collapsed elements. And that would be strange anyway as they would not have been laid out.

Comment: oh you are right. i will edit my question, i thought i tested it with collapsed. sorry.

Comment: There is a lot to explain about this. You might however get a .Net decompiler (like the free JetBrains dotPeek) and take a look at the implementation of e.g. the UIElement.InputHitTest method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF UIElement.IsHitTestVisible=false; still returning hits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813434/wpf-uielement-ishittestvisible-false-still-returning-hits)

Answer (score 10):

I know this is rather old question, but I had similar issue recently and got it working by using [UIElement.InputHitTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.uielement.inputhittest.aspx) method.

I replaced

```
HitTestResult hitTest = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(rootVisual, point);
IInputElement source = hitTest?.VisualHit as IInputElement;
```

With

```
IInputElement source = rootVisual.InputHitTest(point);
```

The second version skips invisible elements (while the first doesn't).